# Using Nest for loop to count unique words

Tags: java, arrays, string, unique

I need to write Java program to parse the words from a String. I can not use the tools that the Java library provides but instead create the code that does everything. The class should be able to break the given sentence into words, where word is defined as the characters between any spaces, commas, or periods. The class should have a constructor that takes a sentence as a parameter. The class should define several public value methods. The class should have one method called "public static void main ()" that demonstrates what the class can do with the specific hard-coded sentence shown below. The demonstration should write this text to the console:

Sentence:
Peas and carrots are ok, but plain peas are better.
Number of words: 10
Number of unique words: 8

This is what I have so far. Counting the number of words total wasn't too hard and it comes out correct. Counting the number of unique words however is the difficult part.

```
public class SP
{
    String sentence; 
    String []words;
    String []uWords;
    public SP (String s)
    {
        sentence = s;
        System.out.println(s);
        words = parse (sentence);
        System.out.println("Number of words is "+ words.length);

    }

public static void main ()
{
    SP sp = new SP("Peas and carrots are ok, but plain peas are better.");
}

public String[] parse(String s)
{
    s = s.replace(".", ""); //delete punctuation
    s = s.replace(",", "");
    s = s.replace("?", "");
    s = s.replace("!", "");
    String w[]=s.split(" "); //split at white spaces
    return w;
}

public int unique (String[]w)
{
    int u=0;
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i=0; i < w.length; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if (w[i].equals(w[j]))
            {
                u++;
            }
        }
    }
    return u;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do a count of how many times each element appears in the list, and add it it another list if the count is one.

Comment: I would use StringBuilder class instead replace and split. And would get sentence as an arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set, by definitions will only contain unique entries, will perform in linear time.

```
String[] words = {"Hello", "World", "Hello"};
Set set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
System.out.println(set.size());
```

Comment: I'm still fairly new with Java so I haven't worked with Hashmaps before. Is this a simple task?

Comment: Actually, scratch the hashmap if you just need count of unique items, use a set.